# Intel Rapid Storage Technology (IRST): puzzled over port number assignements

Tags: windows-7, storage, controller

I am using the tool Intel Rapid Storage Technology (IRST) v9.6.61001 to display the current status of several disks that are built-in and/or connected to a Lenovo W701 Model 4323. The status window shows disks connected on Port 0, Port 1, Port 2 and Port 5.
Port 4 shows empty and Port 3 - well, that one I have never ever seen.

The device-name says that there are 6 ports on the
**Intel AHCI controller:  Intel(R) 5 Series 6 Port SATA AHCI Controller**

But the system report says there are only 5 ports.
**Number of SATA ports:  5**

The status windows and the report assigns disks to ports numbered from 0-5. That would result in 6 ports but that is not the case (according to Intel and the report).

So how comes there is a port numbered with 5 (that port corresponds to the eSATA port) even though that port should be numbered as 4 (ports 0 - 4 >> 5 ports).

And where are the connectors for Port 3 and/or Port 4 on that Laptop?

Anybody knows?

I occupied each available port with either a USB- , eSATA or 1394- device, I can access them all and still port 4 remains empty and port 3 remains to not show up at all.

I am puzzled and hope someone can shed light on this.

```
System Report

System Information
OS name:  Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 
OS version:  6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 7601
System name:  TP-W701
System manufacturer:  LENOVO
System model:  4323CTO
Processor:  GenuineIntel Intel64 Family 6 Model 30 Stepping 5 1.734  GHz
BIOS:  Ver 1.00PARTTBL8, LENOVO - 1280

Intel® Rapid Storage Technology
Kit installed:  9.6.6.1001
User interface version:  9.6.6.1001
Language:  English (United States)
Intel AHCI controller:  Intel(R) 5 Series 6 Port SATA AHCI Controller
Number of SATA ports:  5
Driver version:  10.6.0.1002
ISDI version:  9.6.6.1001

Device Information
Disk on port 0
Port location:  Internal
Status:  Normal
Size:  114 GB
Serial number:  10xxxxxxxxxxxx050
Model:  Corsair CSSD-F120GB2
Firmware:  2.0
System disk:  Yes  
Password protected:  No
Disk data cache:  Enabled
Native command queuing:  Yes  
SATA transfer mode:  Generation 2
Physical sector size:  512 Bytes
Logical sector size:  512 Bytes

Disk on port 2
Port location:  Internal
Status:  Normal
Size:  477 GB
Serial number:  5xxxxxxK
Model:  ST9500420AS
Firmware:  0003LVM1
System disk:  No
Password protected:  No
Disk data cache:  Enabled
Native command queuing:  Yes  
SATA transfer mode:  Generation 2
Physical sector size:  512 Bytes
Logical sector size:  512 Bytes

Disk on port 5
Port location:  External
Status:  Normal
Size:  1,431 GB
Serial number:  WD-Wxxxxxxxxx2
Model:  WDC WD1502FAEX-007BA0
Firmware:  05.01D05
System disk:  No
Password protected:  No
Disk data cache:  Enabled
Native command queuing:  Yes  
SATA transfer mode:  Generation 2
Physical sector size:  512 Bytes
Logical sector size:  512 Bytes

Disk on port 1
Port location:  Internal
Status:  Normal
Size:  0 GB
Serial number:  Mxxxxxxxxx4
Model:  HL-DT-STDVDRAM GT30N
Firmware:  LT10
System disk:  No
Password protected:  No
Disk data cache:  Disabled
Native command queuing:  No
SATA transfer mode:  Generation 1
Physical sector size:  0 Bytes
Logical sector size:  0 Bytes

Empty port
Port:  4
Port location:  External
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Lenovo may have chosen not to enable the ports in the chipset if the design of the complete system didn't use them. They also may be enabled but reserved for internal use (for example, on other models with different options).  What actual problem are you facing?

Comment: @techie007 You certainly got a good point about Lenovo to keep certain ports disabled. I am not facing any hard- or software problem, I want to optimize and to know and understand the internals.